# IntelliJ 2016.1.3: "Command Line App" doesn't create Class

Tags: java, class, templates, intellij-idea, command-line

I'm currently learning Java with the help of IntelliJ (2016.1.3 with jdk1.8.0_92) and encountered following problem with the program:

Everytime I want to create a ["Command Line App"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pI4b.png) via the template, IntelliJ makes a new **Main File** and not a **Main.java class**.
Here is a [Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Rl8.png) of the problem. I've already searched the web and tried to reinstall IntelliJ and the JDK, but that won't fix it...

My current workaround is to create a new Class "Main1.java" and code somewhere else to have the benefit of syntax highlighting. It would be great if you could help me to code directly in the created "Main".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Main.java is the class.  You won't find a solution to this "problem" on the web.  You know far less Java than IntelliJ does.  It's done the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I tried it and it works for me.

Try creating a project without a template and create a new Main class yourself, you will learn more from that.

Also you could contact the JetBrains support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us

Comment: And to everyone who thinks "this is not a bug":
The problem is, that IntellIJ defines the Main.java as a simple file but not as a Java class. Try it yourself and combine the look of his "Main.java" and the normal Java class in IntelliJ (no .java)

I also know that there is a .java file behind the class, but that is what is being displayed to him.